# iPhone localization issue - Portuguese languages

Tags: iphone, localization

When I select the "Português (Portugal)" from the languages, the iPhone automatically uses the pt_PT localization, right?

But, if someone uses "Português" as it's laguage and defines the Region to "Portugal", it won't go for the pt_PT strings, going for pt file instead.

My question is: is there another "two-letter code" associated with the "Português" that differs from the "Português (Portugal)"?

Just because I'd like to set a ??_PT pack for someone using Portugal's region and "Português" as language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, pt_BR for Brazil. It's quite common for applications to offer two portuguese translations, one for "european" portuguese and other for "brazilian" portuguese.

Answer (score 1):

Português (Brazil).